# Unable to install new relic on Ubuntu with Jetty server

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, newrelic, maven-jetty-plugin

I have downloaded newrelic.zip and unzipped into my server root folder which is

```
/myServer-war/newrelic
```

how I am running jetty server:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

I have already set javaagent as:

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}
-javaagent:/myServer/newrelic/newrelic.jar"
```

new relic installation:

```
cd /myServer-war/newrelic
java -jar newrelic.jar install
```

I am getting this error

```
***** ( ( o))  New Relic Java Agent Installer

***** Installing version 3.34.0 ...

* Could not edit start script because:
Could not locate a Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, JBoss7 or Glassfish instance in /myServer-war

* Try re-running the install command with the -s <AppServerRootDirectory> option or from <AppServerRootDirectory>/newrelic.
If that doesn't work, locate and edit the start script manually.

* No need to create New Relic configuration file because:
A config file already exists: /myServer-war/newrelic/newrelic.yml

***** Install incomplete
```

How can I resolve this error?